# How can initial conditions be taken into account to calculate a system's terminal value using the final value theorem or some other technique

Tags: filters, linear-systems, infinite-impulse-response, z-transform, feedback

I wish to calculate the Final Value of the following system given initial conditions **not at rest**, and assuming the X will not change from its initial condition value.

The transfer function is

$$H(z) = \frac{z^{-1} \phi / (1 - \phi z^{-1})}{1 - z^{-1} \psi / (1 - \psi z^{-1})}$$

It arises from the following feedback system

$$Y(z)(1-z^{-1}) = z^{-1}F_{\psi}\cdot Y(z) + z^{-1}F_{\phi}\cdot X(z)$$

where $F_{\alpha}(z)$ is a 1st order high pass filter with parameter $\alpha$ of the form

$$F_{\alpha}(z) = \frac{\alpha (1 - z^{-1})}{1 - \alpha z^{-1}}$$

When the initial conditions are rest, then the final value of the system response to a step in x from $0$ to $x[0]$ is readily obtained using the Final Value Theorem:

$$fv = \lim_{z\rightarrow 1} z(1-z^{-1})H(z)\frac{x[0]}{1 - z^{-1}}$$

which in this case resolves to

$$\frac{x[0] \cdot \phi / (1 - \phi )}{1 - \psi / (1 - \psi )}$$

However this is not where the system will settle if initial conditions are non zero.

**How does one solve for the final value when initial conditions are not zero?**

Comment: i'm gonna have to rewrite your whole question in the language that electrical engineers doing DSP use.  then answer it.  we say "$x[n]$" instead of "$x_t$" and you'll have to be more explicit about what you mean by "$\Delta y_t$, but i think you mean $y[n]-y[n-1]$.  the initial conditions are what we might call "$x[-1]$" and "$y[-1]$".  and, i think you might have to define $G(\cdot)$.

Comment: i have to say, even with the bounty, i dunno that this is worth my time detangling.  there is so much to sort out just expressing the problem in clear, well-defined mathematical terms with notational convention consistent with electrical engineering DSP.

Comment: @robertbristow-johnson. Thanks Robert. Your assumptions on what my notation means are correct. G and F have the same form but potentially different decay constants. I have used phi for G's and psi for F's. Does that make it clearer?

Comment: @robertbristow-johnson. In terms of the bounty, I am happy to increase it, but the system doesn't allow me to grant more than 100 in total. Possibly limited by my account having only 93 points. However you would be doing the broader community a service for which it would be grateful I am sure, as I don't think to date there is a stack exchange answer on how to incorporate initial conditions applied to an actual problem. Your answer would be useful to those who land here later.

Comment: there are still, so many things wrong (as in inconsistent) with your notation that the whole problem needs to be rewritten.

Comment: @robertbristow-johnson ok I have edited the question to use the notation I think you are suggesting. All good now?

Comment: If the system is stable (i.e. not marginally stable or unstable), the final value should not depend on initial conditions. Am I wrong with this assumption?

Comment: if the system is stable, it just depends on the DC gain and the steady-state value of the input.  if the input eventually goes to zero, the output will go to zero.  but if the input is a step (or something added to a step) the output will be $H(1)$ times the final value of the step, which might be, according to the problem, $x[0]$.  so perhaps the answer is $H(1) \cdot x[0]$.

Comment: This particular system's Y will not go to zero even if X eventually goes to zero. But it is stable (with appropriate psi and phi) in the sense that it settles to a finite value so long as X remains constant. The final value depends on the initial conditions.

Comment: The question essentially asks for a methodology to relate the initial conditions to the final value.

Comment: no, that's false, Old.

Comment: @robertbristow-johnson. I see. Which bit do you object to?

Comment: Old, you need to learn or relearn some things we learned way back in EE classes about differential equations and initial conditions.  we had different terms for this: 1. "Homogeneous solution" vs. "Particular solution". 2."Transient response" vs. "Steady-state response".  3. "Natural response" vs. "Forced response".  the first in each pair mean the same thing and also for the second.  now if the system is stable, anything in the transient response will eventually decay to zero.  then use super-position.

Comment: @robertbristow-johnson. I could undoubtedly do with plenty of learning. That's why I asked the question. If you actually know how to solve this problem it would be helpful to see an answer. If you don't know you can just say so.

Comment: @robertbristow-johnson I see you edited the question but I don't see any changes other than converting from one form of Latex to another. Did you make any changes to the content?

Comment: @robertbristow-johnson Actually I think you made an error in the numerator of the last expression for the final value. The numerator's decay constant should be $\phi$ rather than $\psi$. You have also taken out the decay constant subscripting of $F$, probably better with than without. And you have brought back $x_0^+$, probably inadvertently as we probably want to go with $x[0]$

Comment: @robertbristow-johnson. Would be grateful if you could correct your edits

Comment: Your expression for $H(z)$ is not consistent with your description of the problem.  In particular, $H(z)$ contains both $\psi$ and $\phi$, yet you do not mention $\phi$ in your problem statement -- it just crops up at the very end.  Moreover, I went to the effort to try a couple of guesses about what $F_\phi$ and $G_\psi$ really were, and neither ended up with the same $H(z)$.  Stackexchange wants us to give answers to the question that was actually asked, and I can't tell what that is at the moment.  Try **clarifying your question**, preferably by simplifying it.

Comment: Old, i just pulled the $\LaTeX$ expression out of the "title" field of your messy HTML expression.  i just wanted to show you how to do math here at SE.  because if someone were to answer your question, they might want to effortlessly copy an equation or two.

Comment: @TimWescott, I think you must have looked at the problem in an amended state from how I posed it. $\phi$ was inadvertently removed by someone else's edits. Matt L has now kindly edited it back to a consistent state. Essentially how I had prior to other people's edits

Comment: @robertbristow-johnson. Fair enough, the $$ method is certainly better to embed Latex than the html I had. Point taken.

Answer (score 4):

Ah ha!  There's a lot of obfuscation in the problem as stated, plus a bit of over-emphasis on the final value theorem.

> $$H(z) = \frac{z^{-1} \phi / (1 - \phi z^{-1})}{1 - z^{-1} \psi / (1 - \psi z^{-1})} \tag 0$$

OK, so far so good.

> It arises from the following feedback system
>
> $$Y(z)(1-z^{-1}) = z^{-1}F_{\psi}\cdot Y(z) + z^{-1}F_{\phi}\cdot X(z) \tag{1}$$
>
> where $F_{\alpha}(z)$ is a 1st order high pass filter with parameter $\alpha$ of the form
>
> $$F_{\alpha}(z) = \frac{\alpha (1 - z^{-1})}{1 - \alpha z^{-1}} \tag{2}$$

This was bothering me yesterday, but I didn't notice the essential problem.  The general form of the filter described in (2) is first-order, and the delay operators ($z^{-1}$) on the right side of (1) potentially add a second pole.

The original transfer function (0) is in a screwy form, but it appears to be second-order.  So the whole problem manages to worm its way through the pole-zero cancellation check by virtue of being stated in such a non-standard way.  This question deserves to be an extra-credit problem in a control systems class, or problem 10 out of 10 in a final by a particularly sadistic teacher, or perhaps a routine problem if the instructor believes in homework sets that no one will be able to fully solve.

The problem is that there's a pole-zero cancellation that snuck right by me and everyone else.  It's evident in the **left**-hand side of (1), where the *derivative* of $y_k$ is the subject of the equation.

So the reason that you can't solve this problem *as stated* using the final value theorem is that you cannot adequately represent the system using a transfer function.  There may be some way to save this within transfer function notation, but I just tried and failed at the first step, so I'm going to do it in state-space.

So, first, shine some light on this obfuscated* problem.  I'll do that by substituting (2) into (1):

$$Y(z)(1-z^{-1}) = 
     z^{-1}\frac{\psi(1-z^{-1})}{1 - \psi z^{-1}}Y(z) + 
     z^{-1}\frac{\phi(1-z^{-1})}{1 - \phi z^{-1}}X(z) \tag 3$$

Now the pole-zero cancellation becomes painfully evident: we're expressing a filter of the form $1 - z^{-1}$ on the left-hand side, but when we divide through by $1 - z^{-1}$, it no longer appears in the equation.

Oh joy.

So, drawing this out as a feedback loop (and changing from $z^{-1}$ to $z$ notation, because I'm a control systems guy):

[image]

Notation is going to get a bit awkward here.  Bear with me.  The transfer function in (2) can be realized as a state-space system (where $x$ is a state variable, not the system input):

$$\begin{aligned}
x_k = \alpha x_{k-1} + (\alpha - 1)u_k \\
y_k = -x_k + u_k
\end{aligned}
\tag 4
$$

So (awkwardly) noting that $x_{1,k}$ is the first element of the state vector $\mathbf{x}$ at time $k$, but is **not** the system input $x_k$, then the 'top' input to the summing junction is (4) with $\alpha = \phi$ and an extra delay:

$$\begin{aligned}
\begin{bmatrix}x_{1,k} \\ x_{2,k}\end{bmatrix} = 
\begin{bmatrix} \phi & 0 \\ 0 & 0\end{bmatrix} 
  \begin{bmatrix}x_{1,k-1} \\ x_{2,k-1}\end{bmatrix} + 
\begin{bmatrix}\phi - 1 \\ 1\end{bmatrix} x_k \\
u_{1,k} = x_{2, k-1} - x_{1,k-1}
\end{aligned}
\tag 5
$$

The output of the system, $y_k$, is itself just a state variable (oh joy -- not sarcastically this time).  So just let $$y_k = x_{3, k} \tag 6$$.

The filter in the feedback path is again described by (4), with $\alpha = \psi$ and an extra delay:

$$\begin{aligned}
x_{4,k} = \psi x_{4,k-1} + (\psi - 1)x_{3, k} \\
u_{2,k} = x_{4,k-1} - x_{3, k-1}
\end{aligned}
\tag 7
$$

Finally, the integrator in the forward portion of the loop is:

$$x_{2,k} = x_{2,k-1} + u_{1,k} - u_{2,k} \tag 8$$

This goes together into a **fourth-order** system:

$$\begin{aligned}
\mathbf{x}_k = \begin{bmatrix}
\phi & 0 & 0 & 0\\
0 & 0 & 0 & 0 \\
-1 & 1 & 0 & -1 \\
0 & 0 & \psi - 1 & \psi
\end{bmatrix}
\mathbf{x}_{k-1} + \begin{bmatrix}\phi - 1 \\ 1 \\ 0 \\ 0\end{bmatrix}x_k \\
y_k = \begin{bmatrix}0 & 0 & 1 & 0\end{bmatrix}
\end{aligned}
\tag 9
$$

Recast that into $\mathbf{x}_k = A \mathbf{x}_{k-1} + B\,u_k,\,y_k = C\mathbf{x}_k$, and you can test the $A$ and $C$ matrices to see that it is observable, at least for some combinations of $\phi$ and $\psi$ (it is, I checked).  Since there's pole-zero cancellation, we can assume that it isn't controllable (you can check that for yourself).

Because it's observable, we can consider the system
$$\mathbf{x}_k = A \mathbf{x}_{k-1} + \mathbf{x}_0 \delta(k)$$

The response of this system to any given $\mathbf{x}_0$ is $$Y(z) = C(\mathbf{I}z - A)^{-1}\mathbf{x}_0$$  Now you can find the system response for each initial value in $\mathbf{x}$ using the final value theorem.

* I looked it up -- "obfuscate" literally means "to darken, to put into shadow".  So shining a light on the thing really is the antonym of "obfuscate".

Comment: *//This question deserves to be an extra-credit problem in a control systems class, or problem 10 out of 10 in a final by a particularly sadistic teacher, or perhaps a routine problem if the instructor believes in homework sets that no one will be able to fully solve//* ---------- "Obfuscate" is the correct term.  I decided it was too much work to de-obfuscate it.

Comment: I heartily concur -- it took me hours.  I should have stopped at "there's obviously a pole-zero cancellation, don't try".

Comment: well, you deserve the bounty, Tim.

Comment: @TimWescott. Boom! Thanks so much. I'll need to carve out some time to follow this and check it matches simulation but I'm impressed. Upvoted already.

Comment: Don't be surprised at arithmetic errors (and feel free to edit to correct) -- but the conclusion that you've got a hidden pole is obvious when you spell out the $F\phi$ and $G\psi$, and doubly-so when it's in block diagram form.  And I think the method of finding the end answer is correct (you could also try to find $\lim_{k \to \infty} A^k$ and then just use $A^\infty \mathbf{x_0}$ -- it'd be absurd to do it that way by hand, but a snap with a math package).

Comment: Oh -- and if you want to predict the final value from, say, the first four states, you'll need to construct an observer.  This should be possible.

Comment: @TimWescott. I get a bit lost with the $x$ notation for both input and state. Would you be able to add a numerical example with what goes in $C$, $A$, and $x0$ in your final equation for $Y(z)$, and what the resulting final value is calculated to be?

Comment: @TimWescott. Tim, I'm not going to have time to go through your answer in the next 6 hrs before the bounty expires. Not to worry though. I will work out whatever may be necessary to award you a bounty once I go through it and confirm it gives the right numbers. Both yours and Matt's answers deserve the bounty TBH so long as they get to the correct result. I think Matt's approach will ultimately get there as well.

Answer (score 2):

After taking some more time to think about it, I think the problem is finally solved. I haven't digested [Tim's answer](https://dsp.stackexchange.com/a/71586/4298) yet, but from what I can see his approach is different. Furthermore, I thought it would be nice to give a closed-form expression for the final value the system's response will reach given values for $x[-1]$ and $y[-1]$.

The final value is given by

$$\bbox[#f8f1ea, 0.6em, border: 0.15em solid #fd8105]{\begin{align}y[\infty]&=\frac{\phi(1-\psi)x[-1]+y[-1]}{(1-\phi)(1-2\psi)},\quad x[-1]\neq 0,\phi\neq 0,\psi\neq 0\\
y[\infty]&=\frac{y[-1]}{1-2\psi},\quad x[-1]=0\textrm{ or }\phi=0\\y[\infty]&=y[-1]+\frac{\phi x[-1]}{1-\phi},\quad\psi=0\end{align}}\tag{1}$$

As pointed out in Tim's answer and in some comments, the problem is the pole-zero cancellation for $z=1$. The transfer function given in the OP correctly describes the system as an LTI system, i.e., with zero initial conditions, but - due to pole-zero cancellation - it doesn't correctly represent the underlying difference equation if initial conditions are non-zero.

Starting from

$$Y(z)(1-z^{-1})=Y(z)z^{-1}\frac{\psi(1-z^{-1})}{1-\psi z^{-1}}+X(z)z^{-1}\frac{\phi(1-z^{-1})}{1-\phi z^{-1}}\tag{2}$$

we can derive the corresponding difference equation without canceling the zero at $z=1$:

$$y[n]=b_1x[n-1]+b_2x[n-2]+b_3x[n-3]-\ldots\\\ldots -a_1y[n-1]-a_2y[n-2]-a_3y[n-3]\tag{3}$$

where the coefficients $b_k$ and $a_k$ depend on the chosen constants $\phi$ and $\psi$.

Now we can transform $(3)$ back to the $\mathcal{Z}$-domain, using the unilateral $\mathcal{Z}$-transform, which takes the initial conditions into account via the rule

$$\begin{align}\mathcal{Z}\big\{y[n-1]\big\}=z^{-1}Y(z)+y[-1]\end{align}\tag{4}$$

This gives an expression for $Y(z)$, the $\mathcal{Z}$-transform of the output signal resulting from a step at the input with initial conditions $x[-1]$ and $y[-1]$.

Now we can use the final value theorem

$$y[\infty]=\lim_{z\to 1}(1-z^{-1})Y(z)\tag{5}$$

which, after expressing the coefficients $a_k$ and $b_k$ in terms of $\phi$ and $\psi$ and after cancelling the common factor $(1-z^{-1})$ in the numerator and denominator of $(1-z^{-1})Y(z)$ results in Eq. $(1)$ for the final value. Note that $(1)$ is only valid if there actually exists a finite final value. This is not always the case because the system can become unstable even though both high-pass filters are stable.

I've run several simulations of the system confirming Eq. $(1)$. I give one example here: $\phi=0.8$, $\psi=0.4$, $x[-1]=1$, $y[-1]=1$. Eq. $(1)$ predicts a final value of $y[\infty]=37$, which is also the result of the simulation:

[image]

Comment: Thanks for pitching in Matt. I am grateful. I am sure we can get a working answer.
I think we are getting hung up on the "if the system is stable" mantra. 
If you look at the transfer function you will see that this system has memory. The inputs leave a indelible mark on the output that never decays. Simulate it and you'll see. It's a quick exercise in excel, python or whatever your favorite mock up tool. The answer is not $H(1)x[0]$

Comment: well, Mark, we tried.  *"you can lead a horse to water..."*

Comment: @Matt An easy way to see that the system has memory is to write it in the time domain. For the simple case where $\psi = 0$ then $\Delta y[n] = \phi \cdot F_{\phi}$'s infinite sum. So Y is just a converging integral. Convergence is guaranteed by the nature of $F$, which I've specified. And just like any proper integral,I can change its value through the integration constant c or in this case y's initial value $y[-1]$. Ergo. initial conditions do affect the final state of this system. The question is how to calculate that in a systematic general way

Comment: @Matt I think the time domain to z domain conversion destroys the information we need as a result of the unilateral z transform assuming all is 0 prior to $n=0$. The very simplified system's time domain specification is $ y[n] = y[n-1] + F_{\phi}(x[n-1])$ which, given the specified form of $F$, is clearly a convergent infinite sum, which of course depends on initial values $x[-1]$ and $y[-1]$. However when you transform that into the z domain $Y = X \cdot \frac{ \phi  z^{-1} }{1 - \phi z^{-1}}$  and then back to the time domain, you get $y[n] = \phi \cdot (y[n-1] + x[n-1])$

Comment: @Matt which is only the same thing if $ x[-1] = y[-n] = 0$. My initial question had time domain notation aiming to make that clear (unsuccessfully). I was persuaded to transform into the z domain but in retrospect that hides the problem. Where do we go from here?

Comment: The system has poles at $z = 2\psi$ and $z = \phi$.  As long as these poles are stable, then *as time goes to infinity* the contribution of any initial values goes to zero.  That's because the response of this system to its initial values will be in the form $y_k = a (2\psi)^k + b \phi^k$, and $\lim_{k \to \infty} d^k = 0\ \forall\ |d| < 1$.

Comment: @TimWescott Thanks Tim, The issue is that the transfer function doesn't capture the problem. I am no theorist but it strikes me that the transfer function simplifies the difference equation by assuming all is zero prior to $n=0$. If that's correct, I don't think you can solve this type of problem in the z domain and rather need to look at it in time domain state space. My previous comments explain further. Again, I am no theorist so may be wrong but that's what it looks like to me. Thoughts?

Comment: The question states that _"the transfer function arises from the following feedback system $Y(z)(1-z^{-1}) = z^{-1}F_{\psi}\cdot Y(z) + z^{-1}F_{\phi}\cdot X(z)$_. That is a direct transcription of my initial time domain specification $y[n] = y[n-1] + F_{\psi}(y[n-1]) + F_{\phi}(x[n-1])$. Written this way, it is blindingly obvious that $y[-1]$ and $x[-1]$ affect the final state. The problem on transformation to z is that the obvious pole at z=1 cancels out with the zero there, converting the system to a different system that is only equivalent under zero initial conditions.

Comment: @OldSchool: I've added some simulations to my answer. Note that if the final value is finite (i.e., if the total system is stable), then that value cannot depend on the initial condition $y[-1]$ (which is basically the definition of a difference equation describing a stable system). Otherwise (i.e., if the total system is not stable), there is no finite final value.

Comment: @MattL. Thanks Matt. This is great. The issue is that the very nice work you've posted is based on the transfer function $H(z) = \frac{z^{-1} \phi / (1 - \phi z^{-1})}{1 - z^{-1} \psi / (1 - \psi z^{-1})}$. However this does not capture the system properly given by $y[n] = y[n-1] + F_{\psi}(y[n-1]) + F_{\phi}(x[n-1])$ despite it being the correct z-transform of it. That is why my intuition is that the z transform destroys information for this and similar cases (where there is a pole at z=1). I hope you agree that the time domain spec shows initial values affect the (non infinite) final value

Comment: if $\psi = 0$ (there is no feedback) this problem is easy. $y[\infty] = y[-1] + x[-1] \phi / (1 - \phi)$. Showing clearly how initial conditions matter. What I don't know is how to systematically account for $F(y)$ when it is not zero

Comment: @OldSchool: The previous version of my answer was indeed incorrect. I think I've found the correct solution now.

Comment: @MattL.Thanks so much Matt. I have not yet had time to fully digest but looks good. Upvoted already. Will have to decide between the merits of Tim and your answers to select one once I've digested them both. You guys are legends!

Comment: @MattL I have not been able to tie out with your algebra or simulation. Let's see if we can close the gap. Question 1: From your equation $(1)$, when $x[-1] = y[-1] = 0$ then $y[\infty] = 0$ . Could you clarify what Eq $(1)$ is meant to represent? It cannot be the response to a step from $x[-1]$ to $1$ as this would mean there is no response to a unit step when the system starts at rest. I am also thinking that the correct solution must incorporate the initial state of the filters and I don't see that in the equation.  Thoughts?

Comment: @MattL.Question 2: The simulation example moves $x[-1$] from $1$ to what value at $x[0]$?

Comment: @OldSchool: In your question you said "assuming the X will not change from its initial condition value", i.e., the height of the step equals $x[-1]$. If $x[-1]=0$ then, according to that sentence, $x[n]$ will not change, i.e., it will remain zero, hence no output. That's why it makes sense that $y[\infty]=0$ if both $x[-1]$ and $y[-1]$ are zero. I hope this answers both your questions.

Comment: @MattL.Thanks Matt, That's what I was expecting but I couldn't tie out to your answer on those terms  Hence the question.. If $x[-1] = x[0] = x[n]$ for all $n > 0$ and the filter's initial values are both zero (where they would be in steady state), then $y[n] = y[-1]$ for all $n > -1$. i.e. the system produces no change in $y$. Do you not need non zero filter conditions for the system to change $y$ when $x$ doesn't change?

Comment: @OldSchool: You made me think about it again, and it turns out that the original formula I gave doesn't hold for the special cases $\phi=0$, $\psi=0$, and $x[-1]=0$. I've added cases now. I need some more time to make sure that everything is finally correct now, but we're moving in the right direction ...

Comment: @MattL. No problem. But I still think the top equation in box 1 cannot be correct because when $x[n] = 1$ for all $n$, the only way for $y[\infty]$ to be anything other than $y[-1]$ is for the filter's values at $n=-1$ to be non zero. I think you have to take the filters' values at $n=-1$ into account as part of the initial conditions or it will not work

Comment: @OldSchool: I'll check that again as soon as I have some more time. The two special cases are hopefully correct ...

Comment: @MattL.I think they are also incorrect. The filter's initial values at $n = -1$ need to be taken into account I think.

Comment: @OldSchool:Not sure if I understand what you mean, because $x[-1]$ and $y[-1]$ are of course part of the equations.

Comment: @MattL. By filter's initial values I mean $F_{\psi}(y[-1])$ and $F_{\phi}(x[-1])$ which of course can be arbitrarily different from $y[-1]$ and $x[-1]$.  Their values will depend on the path taken to get to $y[-1]$ and $x[-1]$

Comment: "If you look at the transfer function you will see that this system has memory." -- actually, that was probably messing up the experienced people.  **All** systems that can be described with transfer functions have memory -- that's how the system "remembers" it's state from one sample time to the next.  I think by "memory" you mean "an integrator", or "a pole at $z = 1$" -- that's a subset of "memory", not the whole thing.

Comment: @TimWescott That's a fair comment, it is an integrator and indeed that's what my quip about memory was referring to (permanent memory, the path followed leaves an indelible mark that never decays to zero as opposed to systems where steady state does not depend on the path and only have transient memory). Does that mean you agree then with my comments about this particular answer needing correction?

Comment: I haven't read the answer fully, so I can't comment on it.